# Custom TextEdit, how to hide TextInput when it goes wide

Tags: text, input, qml, children, qtquick2

I've trying to create custom text field using `TextInput` element (I need it to use validator and custom style). But I can't hide part of  `TextInput`  content expanding (see image). I have similar problem with other elements, while it have root item (container) what contains other items, childrens can be seen if they are placed out of container coordinates. How can I make childrens parts hidden if they're out of root container?

There is the code, but it's actually just template, I've tried to uze `z` attribute, with no success.

**BreezeQuickLineInput.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    id: root
    property int fontSize: 18
    property BreezeQuickPalette palette: BreezeQuickPalette
    property string text: "Type here..."
    implicitHeight: input.font.pixelSize*2
    implicitWidth: 196
    Rectangle{
        id: body
        color: "transparent"
        anchors.fill: parent
        border {
            color: palette.plasmaBlue
            width: 1
        }
        TextInput{
            id: input
            anchors {
                fill: parent
            }
            font.pointSize: fontSize
            color: palette.normalText
            selectByMouse: true
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciated any help. I've checked `TextInput` documentation, but if you know what topic I should learn please let me know.

[image]

Comment: Why do you set explicitly `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight`?

Comment: What do you mean? How should I set this? I need predefined widget size once it placed on my `ApplicationWindow`. If I set `width` and `height` there is no difference on this behaviour.

Comment: If you want something that's a little easier to use in general, you should check out [TextField](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html) in QtQuick Controls.

Comment: Thanks, but my actual goal is to set any validator to text. As I see it can be done simply with `TextInput`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, really wondered when found `layer` attribute group. I've just turned on `layer.enabled` and my goal was accomplished. There is some lack of info in Qt documents. Unfortunatelly didn't know the purpose of `layer` group previously.

**BreezeQuickLineInput.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    id: root
    property int fontSize: 18
    property BreezeQuickPalette palette: BreezeQuickPalette
    property string text: "Type here..."
    implicitHeight: input.font.pixelSize*2
    implicitWidth: 196
    Rectangle{
        id: body
        color: "transparent"
        anchors.fill: parent
        border {
            color: palette.plasmaBlue
            width: 1
        }
        TextInput{
            id: input
            anchors {
                fill: parent
            }
            font.pointSize: fontSize
            color: palette.normalText
            selectByMouse: true
            layer.enabled: true
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

UPDATE:

My bad, Qt doing business well. My answer was in `Item` description. From Qt docs:

> Item Layers
>
> An Item will normally be rendered directly into the window it belongs to. >However, by setting layer.enabled, it is possible to delegate the item and >its entire subtree into an offscreen surface. Only the offscreen surface, a >texture, will be then drawn into the window.

UPDATE:

Following by [BaCaRoZzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538363/bacarozzo) comment using `clip` attribute of `Item` is less expensive.

> clip : bool
>
> This property holds whether clipping is enabled. The default clip value is false.
>
> If clipping is enabled, an item will clip its own painting, as well as the painting of its children, to its bounding rectangle.

So, I just left it there, believe it can help others with same question.

Comment: Nope, the correct answer is adding [`clip`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#clip-prop) `: true` to `root`. By default the clipping is false and hence painting overcome parent boundary, as you experience. Using `Layers` is works but it's more expensive.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried to add `clip: true` to `input` and it works too. Anyway I was wrong when looking only at elements documentation instead checking `Item` type members. Thanks for comments.

Comment: I had this problem and used clip: true to fix it but now I'd like the TextInput to display starting from the beginning of the string and not the end of it. Any tips?

Answer (score 6):

Just add
clip:true
inside your text input. This will solve your issue.