# Mask a long/wide user input in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am developing a Qt program using QML in which a user has to enter a variable-sized input (up to 50 chars). Since the program window is not big enough I cannot accommodate a 50 char-wide input rectangle. I would like the input box ("inputNameField" below) to act as a mask over the text so that the characters that are out of the input box are not visible. Here is my base code:

```
Rectangle
{
   id: inputNameBox
   onVisibleChanged: if (visible) textNameInput.forceActiveFocus()
   anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
   anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
   color: 'grey'
   radius: 5
   height: parent.height/8
   width: parent.width/4
   TextInput
   {
      id: textNameInput
      autoScroll: true
      anchors.margins: inputNameBox.radius
      anchors.fill: inputNameBox
      font.pixelSize: inputNameBox.height/2
      maximumLength: 50
      horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
      verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter
   }
}
```

I have tried using the inputNameField as an OpacityMask over the textNameInput to no avail.

**EDIT:** duplicate of [Custom TextEdit, how to hide TextInput when it goes wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225162/custom-textedit-how-to-hide-textinput-when-it-goes-wide)

Comment: what is inputNameField?

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for your help. I updated the code to fix this mistake.